# I want to add list in Action on Google

Tags: javascript, node.js, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to add a list in my action, but it showing some error, 
I couldn't identify it. So here is my code,This list will be added in Action on Google,can When I try to deploy this code into firebase it is not taking it.Please give me some tool's name where I can dry run this code

Error when I was deploying it in Firebase.I am pasting all errors, So if anyone can help me into how to interpret the error

26:23  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token ;

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vaibhav/.npm/_logs/2018-08-09T07_44_01_549Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

```
  'use strict'

const {dialogflow}=require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app=dialogflow({debug : true });




app.intent('what is',(conv,{menu})=>
conv.ask("this is today's menu");
conv.ask(new List({
  title : "Today's Menu",
  items : {
    [SELECTION_KEY_ONE]:{
      synonyms:[
      'show me Chinese',
      'Chinese',
    ],
    title : 'Chinese menu',
    description : 'chow(30/-), manchurian(50/-),hakka chow(80/-)',
    image : new Image({
      url : 'ibb.co/jJHNMU',
      alt : 'chinese food',
    }),
  }
  [SELECTION_KEY_TWO]:{//showing error in this line near column
    synonyms:[
    'show me Veg',
    'Veg',
  ],
  title : 'Veg menu',
  description : 'chow(30/-), manchurian(50/-),hakka chow(80/-)',
  image : new Image({
    url : 'ibb.co/jJHNMU',
    alt : 'chinese food',
  }),
},
},
}  ));
);


exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: You say it's "showing some error". What is that error as it would be useful to help track down the cause rather than just trying to interpret your code

Comment: @TommyBs updated

Answer (score 0):

When running `eslint .` before deploying your function, the tool will automatically check for potential issues in your code related to style and functionality.

Looking at the error `26:23 error Parsing error: Unexpected token ;`, I looked at line 26 in your code, which did not appear to be that useful of an indicator:

```
image : new Image({
  url : 'ibb.co/jJHNMU',
  alt : 'chinese food',
}),
```

But I did find several issues around that section that may have resulted in this error, or possibly errors down the line.

Right now each item in your list is denoted with `[SELECTION_KEY_ONE]`. This means that the object is going to use, as the key, the value from a variable named `SELECTION_KEY_ONE`. This variable does not exist, and should cause an error. To remedy this, you should:

- Create a new variable for each key: `const SELECTION_KEY_ONE = 'one'`
- Hardcode the value of each key: `items: { 'one': { ...`

The first option is preferable, as you'll be able to separate constants to a logical place and reuse them everywhere.

Another issue seems to be your list object appears to close early, causing a potential syntax error.

```
items : {
  [SELECTION_KEY_ONE]:{
    synonyms:[
      'show me Chinese',
      'Chinese',
    ],
    title : 'Chinese menu',
    description : 'chow(30/-), manchurian(50/-),hakka chow(80/-)',
    image : new Image({
      url : 'ibb.co/jJHNMU',
      alt : 'chinese food',
    }),
  }
  [SELECTION_KEY_TWO]:{//showing error in this line near column
  // ...
```

A JSON object is setup as a series of key-value pairs, separated by commas. Then it closes out. Looking at this snippet, it seems like you close your first item without having a comma after the `}` and before `[SELECTION_KEY_TWO]`, causing the error.

As an aside, it may be helpful to use identations and spacing to better show the hierarchy of execution. That can make your code more readable for yourself and others, and can allow you to identify potential errors faster.

Comment: thank you for your answer, one question, do I have do declare conv function always in app.intent()?

Comment: No, you will get `conv` as a parameter, so what you have now in that regard is fine.